# Element Query to retrieve top number of elements

Tags: xcode-ui-testing, uitest, xcuitest

I know that there is a firstMatch variable which can be used to get the first element the query finds. 
However, I can't find anything to retrieve the first or top number of elements found.

For now, I've been taking in the whole array using allElementsBoundByIndex and just iterating through the number i need.

If there isn't a way to easily get the top elements, how can I optimize that?

Edit: 
This is the code I'm using to handle it.

```
var listOfCells = app.cells.matching(predicateIDStartsWith(string)).allElementsBoundByIndex
while 0<listOfCells.count {
    let reply = handler(listOfCells.removeFirst())
    if reply > 0 {
        return reply
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the count of elements matching your query, then you can directly access the element at the last index.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let query = app.cells
let cellCount = query.count
let lastCell = query.element(boundBy: cellCount - 1)
```

Since `firstMatch` is a lazy optimization, something similar for the last element would not be an optimisation - the concept of adding `.firstMatch` is designed to prevent the need to work out the full contents of the list of elements. Unfortunately, XCTest doesn't offer inverted view hierarchy traversal, so there aren't a lot of optimisations you can do when looking for the last item in a list.

Comment: While your explanation was indeed helpful, I was more asking on getting a list of elements, specifically as an example the first 10 elements, 14 or 5. Do you think i should edit anything in the original question?